# Manually programming the splash screen to appear at arbitrary times

Tags: unity-game-engine

In our app, the `splash screen` appears when we start the app (or build to Android device) as the app is loading, which is done through the Unity's `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player` but we now have a feature that sometimes in the middle of the app **also** re-starts the app, so we would like to code this behavior, so that we can show a **different** splash screen if the app re-starts **mid-usage**.

We cannot seem to be able to figure out how to do this programmatically, or where exactly in the app code, so we would appreictae any help.

What we do know (and have already implemented) is through:

```c#
PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastShownComponent", menuId);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

which remembers if this is the first time the app is starting (original splash image) or whether the user is mid-usage, but how do we specify another image to be loaded as `splash screen` when the app is reloading mid-usage?

EDIT: more details...

Previously, we only had the following code:

```c#
if (_callbackUri == null)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("ReloadScene");
}
```

Now, we **force** the app to re-start mid-usage (for a specific reason) by:

```c#
if (_callbackUri == null)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Restarting", 1);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    AndroidPlugin.Restart();
    #else
    SceneManager.LoadScene("ReloadScene");
    #endif
}
```

However, when it restarts, obviously it re-loads the same splash screen image that is in the player settings.

We probably need to add code just below `AndroidPlugin.Restart();` to load a new splash screen image, but how do we do that? Do we need a new scene for that?

Comment: Is it possible to have a blank scene that basically loads the 2 different splash screen depending on what was saved out in the playerprefs?  So for example, game launches, your initial scene is a blank scene with a script that loads the splash screen depending on if you set `PlayerPrefs.SetString("GameReload", reloadingValue)`  then everytime you actually open the game it sets that value to false?

Comment: @Eddge Thanks for your reply, but I am not sure if I understand you. I will edit my post to add details, so it would be great if you read it again and elaborate on your comment question. Thanks

Comment: Are you talking in regards to the unity splash screen itself?  For example you want it to play the animated version of the unity logo, the first time it launches, then when you call `AndroidPlugin.Restart()` you want it to play the standing still logo?  Or are you talking about your own custom splash screen?  I am unsure if you can change the way the Unity Splash screen is displayed.  Which is why I mentioned adding a a blank scene that would load 1 of 2 scenes for your own custom splash screen.

Comment: As far as I know, when you build the project it only builds 1 scene for the Unity Splash screen.

Comment: @Eddge Not Unity's splash screen itself, but a custom image of a company. The first time it launches, this company image, and then everytime the user restarts (which calls `AndroidPlugin.Restart()` which re-starts the app mid-usage) a different image. I see your point about adding a a blank scene that would load 1 of 2 scenes for my own custom splash screen. I think this is what I need. Do you have more details, like helper code or where I can look to find some examples of this? I think your suggestion is what I need...

Comment: @Eddge The splash screen image seems to be one for the whole app (Unity project) so even if I add a a blank scene that could load 1 of 2 scenes, how could I have different splash screens for each scene?

Comment: I posted an answer with 2 examples of ways you could go about this, since you can't edit the unity splash screen directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments:

Quickest way to test this is to create a blank scene, add a gameobject to that scene name it something like SplashLoader and give it a script.

the only thing you need in that script is the start method,

```
void Start()
{
    // Default to 0 incase this value isn't stored
    int reloaded = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Restarting", 0); 

    // Reset to 0 so if the game is closed without restarting it will display the correct scene
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Restarting", 0); 

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    if(reloaded == 1)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("ReloadScene"); 
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SplashScene");
    }
}
```

From here you would create 2 scenes, one for your normal SplashScene and 1 for your ReloadScene.  In those scene you can create a canvas object and add an image to it then change the image depending which scene it is.

Another Option if you want to use a single scene and keep the same animation say you have an effect where your logo fades in, you can do this:

Create a scene for your splash screen, make that your 0 index scene, add a canvas to it and an image, then use an animator to get your splash screen effect going.

Add a script to your image object, to change the picture depending on what the preference stores, you can use almost the same code as the start method above, instead of calling the `SceneManager` to load the scene you would just update the image.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

The splash screen (and everything associated with it) can only be changed/modified inside the editor (via Inspector or via code using the `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SplashScreen` class).

To add insult to injury, on Android you MUST have a splash screen: if you try to disable it via the Player Settings, the Android app won't work.

So, the only solution you have is to use a blank splash screen, and then two different starting scenes (with different backgrounds) which are loaded, mutually exclusively, if you are launching or restarting the app (by using a field in `PlayerPrefs` as you correctly thought).

**EDIT**

Actually, you don't even need multiple scenes to accomplish what you want to do.

Create just one scene (let's call it `SplashScene`), with just the `Main Camera` and a `Canvas` with an `Image`.
Attach this script to the `Main Camera`:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Image backgroundImage;
    [SerializeField]
    Sprite launchBackground, restartBackground;

    private void Awake() {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Background Splash Screen"))
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Background Splash Screen", 0);
        int background = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Background Splash Screen");
        switch (background) {
            case 0:
                backgroundImage.sprite = launchBackground;
                break;
            case 1:
                backgroundImage.sprite = restartBackground;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid Background Splash Screen PlayerPref value!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course `SplashScene` should be at index 0 in the standalone scenes list.

The only other thing you need to do is to add

`PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Background Splash Screen", 0);`

before any `Application.Quit();` method you call in your project and

`PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Background Splash Screen", 1);`

before any `AndroidPlugin.Restart();` method in your code.

Don't forget to assign the sprites and the image reference to the variables of the script via Inspector ofc (you can get them via `GetComponent` and asset loading if you prefer, it's up to you).

That's pretty much it. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it. Cheers

Comment: I created a new scene and added the splash image to its canvas image with native size. I then added it to my build scenes with index 4 and addede the following code: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Restarting", 1); PlayerPrefs.Save(); #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR SceneManager.LoadScene(4); AndroidPlugin.Restart(); #else SceneManager.LoadScene("ReloadScene"); #endif` However, it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you how to do what you need.