# changing load screen with every start-up

Tags: startup

We've been developing an app over the past month and I wanted to ask if it's possible to select a different load screen with every new app start-up.

It would be the same design, but the background colour and logo colour would change. We have 5 different files with contrasting colour schemes and we thought it could be a cool gimmick if the start-up screen would also show a different image every time a user uses our app.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thank you so much for any help,
Marvin.

Comment: With so little information given it's impossible to give you any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually programming the splash screen to appear at arbitrary times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919479/manually-programming-the-splash-screen-to-appear-at-arbitrary-times)

Comment: Not an "exact" duplicate but the concept is the same.